# A feature to integrate bug-reporting?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I don't know how many posts here in AskUbuntu are closed for being bug reports. Is it possible instead of just closing the post, we bring some feature that would route these posts to the proper bug-reporting sites? Wouldn't that increase the participation in manual participation in bug-reporting and perhaps wider audience than it would have been otherwise? And hence developers would know which bugs are with more community interest. Again I don't have the access to the stats here. :)

So is there a scope for a tag like `bug-reporting`?

Comment: Bug reports are automated already with apport - I am not sure how you would integrate that with a web server. Also, writing a decent bug report takes education and time, as a developer it is frustrating to get a bug report that simply states "broken". See http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html and try to automate all that ;)

Comment: things other than crashes.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a question that tells people how to do that, but we can't launch the information gathering tools to report bugs from the webpage.  So, I'm not sure that's a do-able solution.

It seems to be we'ld get a lot of bugs that nobody follows up or posts troubleshooting data on.

Comment: am just frustrated with fresh new-install sluggish system.

Comment: @precise That is understandable but not every problem is a bug (sluggishness could be because the graphics card can't keep up or such, or hardware problems).  The other problem is that Ask Ubuntu can't run the bug report tools as hbdgaf says, and in fact the quality of bug reports would become very bad, with a ton of bug reports being marked as duplicates or being marked Invalid or any number of "closing"-equivalent actions in the triage process.  It's just not feasible to have Bug Reporting integration with Launchpad on Ask Ubuntu.